# Integral Substitution with complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, substitution

I want to show that $\forall k,x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x+ik)^2/2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(k-ix)^2/2}\mathrm{d}k
$$
Can I just $u$ substitute these two integrals? Is it allowed to let
$$
u=x+ik\Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=1
$$
$$
v=k-ix\Rightarrow\frac{dv}{dk}=1
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x+ik)^2/2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-u^2/2}\mathrm{d}u=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-v^2/2}\mathrm{d}v=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(k-ix)^2/2}\mathrm{d}k?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs to apply a bit of caution upon the change of variables.  Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathscr{R}}e^{-(x+ik)^2/2}\,dx&=\lim_{(-L,U)\to (-\infty,\infty)}\int_{-L}^U e^{-(x+ik)^2/2}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{(-L,U)\to (-\infty,\infty)}\int_{-L+ik}^{U+ik} e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

Tp proceed, the key is applying [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) to $(1)$ to deform the contour from $-L+ik$ to $U+ik$ to the straight-line contour from $-L$ to $U$.  Proceeding accordingly yields

$$\int_{\mathscr{R}}e^{-(x+ik)^2/2}\,dx=\lim_{(-L,U)\to (-\infty,\infty)}\int_{-L}^{U} e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

and we are done!

Comment: can you elaborate on the deformation of your contour? Is it that you're drawing a rectangle with vertices $(-L, -L + ik, U + ik, U)$ and noting that the top horizontal path must cancel the bottom horizontal path since there are no holes inside? Or is it a different line of reasoning?

Comment: You have it precisely!  The deformation is indeed that rectangle. And it is straightforward to show that the contributions from the sides approach $0$ as $L$ and $U$ approach $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $I=\int e^{-{1 \over 2} (x+ik)^2} dx = \int e^{-{1 \over 2} (-t+ik)^2} dt= \int e^{-{1 \over 2} (-x+ik)^2} dx$ using the substitution $t=-x$. Since $I = \int e^{-{1 \over 2} (x-ik)^2} dx$ (since $y^2=(-y)^2$), you have the desired result.